# Self made text-to-speech in javascript doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html

We made a text-to-speech function in javascript. The only problem now is that it doesn't work properly. When the play button is pressed, it is supposed to tell everything that's within the body tags. The problem is that most of the times it's not working and when it does, it's telling also the javascript code which it's outside of the body tag. How can i fix this so that it's working everytime the play button is pressed and it's only telling everything in the body tag?

```js
onload = function() {
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window) with(speechSynthesis) {

    var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
    var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
    var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');
    var flag = false;

    playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
    pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
    stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

    function onClickPlay() {
      if (!flag) {
        flag = true;
        utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('body').textContent);

        utterance.lang = 'nl-NL';
        utterance.rate = 0.7;
        utterance.onend = function() {
          flag = false;
          playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
          stopEle.className = 'stopped';
        };
        playEle.className = 'played';
        stopEle.className = '';
        speak(utterance);
      }
      if (paused) {
        playEle.className = 'played';
        pauseEle.className = '';
        resume();
      }
    }

    function onClickPause() {
      if (speaking && !paused) {
        pauseEle.className = 'paused';
        playEle.className = '';
        pause();
      }
    }

    function onClickStop() {
      if (speaking) {
        stopEle.className = 'stopped';
        playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
        flag = false;
        cancel();

      }
    }

  }

  else { /* speech synthesis not supported */
    msg = document.createElement('h5');
    msg.textContent = "Detected no support for Speech Synthesis";
    msg.style.textAlign = 'center';
    msg.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    msg.style.color = 'white';
    msg.style.marginTop = msg.style.marginBottom = 0;
    document.body.insertBefore(msg, document.querySelector('div'));
  }

}
```

```html
<button id=play>Play</button>
<button id=pause>Pause</button>
<button id=stop>Stop</button>
```

Comment: Why not put the text in a div or textarea instead of reading the body content?

Comment: Even if we put it in a div and read the div we still have the same problem

Comment: Works for me as long as I click stop before play again. I think you are missing some pause=true and if (speaking)

Comment: Same as @mplungjan. The issue with it reading the code happens when your code is in the `body`, which is also completely expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the DIV you want the Speech recognition to read from:

```
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id=play>Play</button>
        <button id=pause>Pause</button>
        <button id=stop>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="readFrom">
        Just a test o my friend mplungjan
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            if ('speechSynthesis' in window)
                with (speechSynthesis) {

                    var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
                    var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
                    var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');
                    var flag = false;

                    playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
                    pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
                    stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

                    function onClickPlay() {
                        if (!flag) {
                            flag = true;
                            utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('#readFrom').innerHTML);

                            utterance.lang = 'nl-NL';
                            utterance.rate = 0.7;
                            utterance.onend = function () {
                                flag = false;
                                playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
                                stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                            };
                            playEle.className = 'played';
                            stopEle.className = '';
                            speak(utterance);
                        }
                        if (paused) {
                            playEle.className = 'played';
                            pauseEle.className = '';
                            resume();
                        }
                    }

                    function onClickPause() {
                        if (speaking && !paused) {
                            pauseEle.className = 'paused';
                            playEle.className = '';
                            pause();
                        }
                    }

                    function onClickStop() {
                        if (speaking) {
                            stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                            playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
                            flag = false;
                            cancel();

                        }
                    }

                }

            else { /* speech synthesis not supported */
                msg = document.createElement('h5');
                msg.textContent = "Detected no support for Speech Synthesis";
                msg.style.textAlign = 'center';
                msg.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                msg.style.color = 'white';
                msg.style.marginTop = msg.style.marginBottom = 0;
                document.body.insertBefore(msg, document.querySelector('div'));
            }

        }
    </script>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple. I see on your line that you are querying all the body text Content but that should not be it. Go on your JS Console and query: `document.querySelector('body').textContent`

You should see exactly what you are passing as arguments to:

utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('body').textContent);

So now it's up to you, you would have to filter what you want to be read by putting it in a specific DIV or stripping HTML from the page according to a complex logic keeping just what you want to read.

Comment: Pardon me.. You have to add 

console.log(document.querySelector('body').textContent);

right before the line:

utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('body').textContent);

In order to see what you are passing to the function (only Play Pause and Stop).